# Scale group of UIViews but keeping its position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, transform, scale

I am trying to scale multiple UIViews at once with the pinch gesture(On the base view). Though it looked straight forward, I am facing hard time getting it working properly.

Assume I have 3 views stacked like this

```
----------------------------------------------
|                                            |
|    -------                      --------   |   
|    |     |                      |      |   |
|    |  V1 |   ---------------    |      |   |
|    |     | X |     v2      |  Y |   v3 |   |
|    -------   ---------------    |      |   |
|                                 --------   |
---------------------------------------------
```

On pinch, I am scaling each of the 3 views by calculating the transform using the scale propery

```
CGAffineTransform v1Transform =  CGAffineTransformScale( v1.transform,recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
v1.transform = v1Transform
CGAffineTransform v2Transform =  CGAffineTransformScale( v2.transform,recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
v2.transform = v2Transform
CGAffineTransform v3Transform =  CGAffineTransformScale( v3.transform,recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
v3.transform = v3Transform
```

And change the center of each view using the current scale, like this

```
   CGPoint v1Center = CGPointMake(v1.center.x * recognizer.scale,  node.imgView.center.y * recognizer.scale);
   CGPoint v2Center = CGPointMake(v2.center.x * recognizer.scale,  node.imgView.center.y * recognizer.scale);
   CGPoint v3Center = CGPointMake(v3.center.x * recognizer.scale,  node.imgView.center.y * recognizer.scale);
  v1.cente = v1Center;
  v2.center = v2Center;
  v3.center = v3Center;
```

Though this scales  each of the 3 views uniformly, I feel the center point is too off and the scaling looks weirder. please check the below screen capture of the issue

[image]

As you can see, though the scale works as expected and all 3 views scale together. Center is still an issue. I want the scale to be done from all 3 views actual place, I dont want them to move like this in the gif.

Is there a way? any help is much appreciated

Comment: Don't change the position of centre of the views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the usual behavior when scaling a group of elements, which is for them to scale from the center of all selected elements.

I've done this before, it's in Swift and it uses some extensions of a library I made called [CGMath](https://github.com/EmilioPelaez/CGMath)*, but it should be good enough as pseudocode:

```
let scale = recognizer.scale
//  Reset the scale of the recognizer. We'll scale the views by the change in the last tick.
recognizer.scale = 1
//  Get the center of all selected views as a CGPoint
let center = views.map { $0.center }.reduce(CGPoint.zero, +) / CGFloat(views.count)
views.forEach {
    //  Scale the view
    $0.scale *= scale
    //  Get the distance from this view to the center of all views, this is a CGPoint
    let distance = $0.center - center
    //  Multiply the distance by the scale and add it to the center of all views. Set that as the view's center.
    $0.center = center + (distance * scale)
}
```

*the extensions in CGMath are what make it possible to add and subtract points.

Comment: thanks @EmilioPelaez, its perfect. works like a charm. :) Added my obj-c version of your code down here incase anyones interested.

Comment: I have a similar issue for rotating the grouped views, would be great if you can have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052198/rotate-group-of-uiviews-together-from-common-center

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you are also scaling the view's x and y positions in relation to 0,0 which is the corner of the screen. You need to do it in relation to the centre of the screen or perhaps the centre of your pinch gesture. I can't remember off the top of my head but I think there's a way to specify the anchor point of a scale, if not you'll have to calculate the position adjustments manually.

Answer (score 0):

@EmilioPelaez Answer works as expected. This is the obj-c version of his pseudocode incase anyone interested

```
CGPoint newCenter =CGPointZero;
for(UIView *node in self.selectedNodes){
    newCenter = CGPointMake(newCenter.x + node.center.x, newCenter.y + node.center.y);
}

newCenter = CGPointMake(newCenter.x/self.selectedNodes.count, newCenter.y/self.selectedNodes.count);
for(UIview *node in self.selectedNodes){
    CGAffineTransform newTransform =  CGAffineTransformScale( node.transform,recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    node.transform = newTransform;
    CGPoint distance = CGPointMake(node.center.x - newCenter.x, node.center.y - newCenter.y);
    CGPoint delta= CGPointMake(distance.x * recognizer.scale, distance.y * recognizer.scale);
    node.center =CGPointMake(newCenter.x + delta.x, newCenter.y + delta.y);
}
```